# Cannot find name 'platform'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am new to ionic2 and angular2 framework and i am trying to learn by creating small apps.this time i wanted to create an app to open an webpage (url). I got few errors and solved some by findind solutions here but I couldnot solve this error.,cannot find platform. I have added my .ts file .Any suggestion would be really helpfull. Thank you.

```
     Home.ts

import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';

declare var cordova:any;

@Page({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {
constructor(platform: Platform) {
platform = platform;

}

 launch(url) {
 **platform**.ready().then(() => {
 cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_system", "location=true");
 });

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are setting a local variable from the constructor declare it in the class or set an access specifier to the constructor parameter.Typescript will set it as a class variable.
**Option 1:**

```
platform:any;
constructor(platform: Platform) {
this.platform = platform;

}
```

**Option 2:**

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {}
```

And access as:

```
this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})
```

Comment: Thank you so much..,option 1 worked for me !! @suraj

Comment: hallo suraj.,The app is successfully build but there is runtime error in the ionic serve..,the error:cannot find the module "ionic-framework/ionic" which i used to import "page". Do you have any idea ?